# SoapUI Java Integration with Authentication

Tags: java, wsdl, soapui

I have been trying to make use of SoapUI through Java by importing the WSDL into the project with authentication.

During the import step I keep getting an error that just mentions that it failed to load the URL.

The code has been tested with WSDL's that do not feature authentication and have had no issues.

I have tried adding the credentials to URL for the WSDL as well with no luck.

The code used is as follows:

```
wsdlProject = new WsdlProject("wsdlProject");    
ProjectConfig config = wsdlProject.getConfig(); 

wsdlProject.setPropertyValue("SecurityType", "HTTPBasic");
wsdlProject.setPropertyValue("AuthUserName", "User");
wsdlProject.setPropertyValue("AuthPassword", "Pass");

wsdlInterface =  WsdlImporter.importWsdl(wsdlProject,URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but have you tried to pass the credentials with the URL?
**[protocol]://[user]:[pass]@[path]**

in JAX-WS you would add Basic Authentication like this:

```
Service s = new Service();
Port port = s.getPort();

port.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "myusername");
port.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "mypassword");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I have without any luck. Are there any other approaches that could be used to specify basic authentication for a WSDL through Java?

Comment: Thanks for the information, I could not find a similar approach to work with SoapUI

Comment: It looks like this : [protocol]://[user]:[pass]@[path]
...may have worked since I do not get authorization errors on my SoapUI log. The log now mentions "[WsdlLoader] Failed to load url", nothing more than that.